# How to modify springboot configuration parameters and save to the configuration file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm currently writing a SpringBoot app implementing the CommandLineRunner.

I managed to successfully load configuration from a yaml file which can be on the on the resources folder or a file on the same path as the jar file.

I've also managed to modify the configuration in runtime however I need to persist these changes to the yaml file on the file system.

Does anybody know a "Spring way" to get it done ? or alternatively an easy way...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FileOutputStream to write the changed file to the filesystem.

Comment: That sounds like the hardest way to do it. I was wondering if spring does not have something easier to just save the configuration.